# Improving PyQGIS processing time when using "Select by location"

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, performance, select-by-location

When running PyQGIS processing with [`"qgis:selectbylocation"`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-location) it takes a lot of time (sometimes it get to an hour).

Is there is a way to make it work faster?

```py
parameters = {
    "INPUT": layer1,
    "INTERSECT": layer2,
    "METHOD": 0,
    "PREDICATE": [0],
    "OUTPUT": "TEMPORARY_OUTPUT",
    }
    
result = processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:selectbylocation", parameters)["OUTPUT"]
```

Comment: Do your layers have a spatial index?

Comment: @MrXsquared Yes

Comment: How many features in each layer? Are any of them big multi-polygons/lines/points?

Comment: @BERA layer1 is 536982 and won't change. Layer2 will change everytime , for this example it has 3078 features. One is polygon and the second is point